# automysqlbackup then rsync

Tags: mysql, backup, rsync, ssh-keys

I'm trying to configure an automatic MySQL backup solution under an Ubuntu server.

I have chosen `automysqlbackup` and `rsync` for this purpose (does it seem to be a good choice ?)

`rsync` will be used in the `automysqlbackup` `#POSTBACKUP` callback to send the backup to a remote server after each backup.

I found that `automysqlbackup` uses root as default user to make his operations.

How can I make `automysqlbackup` use a dedicated linux user so I'd be able to easily manage ssh keys and things like that ?

**Update:**

The script attached to `#POSTBACKUP` would resemble:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -ar /var/lib/automysqlbackup/ \
  backup@my_remote_backup_server:~/remote_backup/$HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to another user before running `rsync`, something like this:

```
su - mysql -s /bin/bash -c 'rsync -ar ...'
```

Other some solutions that you might interested in:

- http://www.zmanda.com/backup-mysql.html
- http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/

Comment: What does your postbackup script look like?

Comment: See my updated.

Comment: Run it as `mysql` user instead of `root`. Make sure that `mysql` user has write permission to `/var/lib/automysqlbackup/`.

Comment: `automysqlbackup` runs automatically through cron and following directives from a config file. So I don't know where I should change this user. This config file does not specify the user.

Comment: Run it as a cron job of `mysql` instead of `root`.

Comment: My daily cron is now `test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup && su -c /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup mybackup` but it is still creating backup files as `-rw------- root root` (`mybackup` is my backup user)

Comment: From `root`, type `crontab -u mysql -e`, then call `automysqlbackup` to run it as `mysql` user.